# how to fix "index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page' "?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make a sort by feature in my website and I am having this problem.
this is my code:

```
@app.route("/", defaults={'page':0, 'type':'top'})
@app.route("/<type>")
@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
def index(type, page):
    perpage=5
    startat=page*perpage
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    if type=='top':
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT %s, %s ORDER BY upvotes ASC", (startat,perpage))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template("index.html", dat=data)
    elif type=='new':
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT %s, %s ORDER BY created_at ASC", (startat,perpage))
        data = cur.fetchall()
        cur.close()
        return render_template("index.html", dat=data)
```

so what's the problem.

*PS: is this a good approach for a sort by feature along with the pagination, if not, what's the best approach?*

THAnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to get to `index()` without defining what the type is, or without defining what the page is.

- If you go to `/t`, then you're calling `index(type="t")`. In this case, you're not specifying `page`.
- If you go to `/page/p`, you're calling `index(page="p"`). In this case, you're not specifying `type`.

Since the function itself doesn't have default values for those arguments, it throws an error. The easy solution here is, instead of putting the defaults in `@app.route("/")`, put them in the function header itself:

```
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<type>")
@app.route('/page/<int:page>')
def index(type="top", page=0):
    ...
```

Those default values will get overwritten if `<type>` or `<page>` is specified.